# Laravel 5.8 request data is empty

Tags: laravel

router.php

> Route::get('/p00001/edit/{center}/{id}',
>   'Dashboard\Programs\P00001Controller@edit');
>   Route::put('/p00001/update/{center}/{id}',
>   'Dashboard\Programs\P00001Controller@update');

form.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="zh-TW">
<body>
    <form id="mainform" action="/dashboard/programs/p00001/update/JPN/3121-111907230007" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      {{ method_field('put') }}
      <input type="text" value='1234' id="inpTest" name="inpTest">
      <input type="submit" name="inpSubmit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

P00001Controller.php

> ```
> public function __construct(Request $request, P00001Service $P00001Service )
> {
>     $this->request = $request;
> }
>
> public function update($center, $id)
> {
>     $data = $this->request->all();
>     echo "<pre>", print_r($_POST, 1), "</pre>";
>     echo "<pre>", print_r($this->request->all(), 1), "</pre>";
> }
> ```

I got empty array.

I created a test.php

```html
<?php echo "<pre>", print_r($_POST, 1), "</pre>"; ?>
```

If I change the action to test.php, it's ok, I can get $_POST data.

I searched for hours, no solution can fix my problem.

Comment: where is `test.php` file?

Comment: /public/test.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the problem. I use LaravelLocalization package. So if the locale is not provided, it redirects! After redirect, there are only url parameters!!

The action should be
/ja-JP/dashboard/programs/p00001/update/JPN/3121-111907230007

Answer (score 1):

Delete the Request object from construct and add it into the update function.

```
public function update(Request $request, $center, $id) {
      $data = $request->all();
      //code
}
```

Edit:
I added the link of laravel documentation for you.

> To obtain an instance of the current HTTP request via dependency injection, you should type-hint the Illuminate\Http\Request class on your controller method.

Visit [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests) to explore more.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make route as named route

```
Route::get('/p00001/edit/{center}/{id}','Dashboard\Programs\P00001Controller@edit')->name('edit'); 
Route::put('/p00001/update/{center}/{id}', 'Dashboard\Programs\P00001Controller@update')->name('update');
```

In view

```
 <form id="mainform" action="{{route('update',['center' => 'JPN','id' => '3121-111907230007'])}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  {{ method_field('put') }}
  <input type="text" value='1234' id="inpTest" name="inpTest">
  <input type="submit" name="inpSubmit">
</form>
```

In controller

```
public function update(Request $request,$center, $id)
{
$data = $request->all();
echo "<pre>", print_r($_POST, 1), "</pre>";
echo "<pre>", print_r($request->all(), 1), "</pre>";
}
```

Don't create request object in constructor...Create in function definition.

Comment: I have two parameters. If  request created in update(), It says: "Argument 1 passed to ... update() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given"

Comment: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` in the top of controller

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have the DB `facade`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question